# PSQL Copy CSV data to postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have an empty table in postgreSQL :

```
CREATE TABLE public.tbltesting
(
    "ID" integer,
    "testValue" numeric
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

I have a CSV file with the following data :

```
ID,testValue
1,2.0
2,3.33
3,4
```

The file is huge and requires a bulk copy and so I am trying to run the following command from PSQL :

```
\copy tblfoodnutrients FROM 'C:\temp\tbltestingbulk.csv' with CSV HEADER
ERROR:  relation "tblfoodnutrients" does not exist
```

I have also tried the following :

```
\copy public.tblfoodnutrients FROM 'C:\temp\tbltestingbulk.csv' with CSV HEADER
ERROR:  relation "public.tblfoodnutrients" does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

DUH!   My connection was missing the database name to begin with.